# css3 rotate according to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do the following:
Create a square div on the screen and whenever the cursor is hovering it, the square should horizontally rotate (rotateY).
This is what I have done:
http://jsbin.com/ujolop/1/edit

HTML:

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var maxRotate = 30; //deg

$('.a').on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var $this = $(this),
      width = $this.width(),
      center = width / 2,
      left = $this.position().left,
      curRelPosX = event.clientX - left,
      percent = (curRelPosX - center) / center,
      rotate = percent * maxRotate;

  $this.css('transform', 'rotateY(' + rotate + 'deg)');
});
```

This isn't work. It jumps and most of the time doesn't respond to the cursor hover.
 Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
If I am right, for unknown reasons this is working fine in firefox but doesn't working good in chrome. Any idea why? Do I use the correct event (mousemove)?

Comment: @adeneo: Your link is wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's work either, trying to fix stuff like this is fun :)

Comment: @user1846192: Agree! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited some of the calculation in your JavaScript :

```
left = $this.parent().offset().left,
curRelPosX = event.pageX - left,
percent = (curRelPosX <= center) ? curRelPosX / center : (width - curRelPosX) / center
```

If you `console.log(left)` you can see there is a problem of accuracy, the code above is also better to determine the exact `curRelPosX`.

About the `percent` calculation, if you go further than the center (maximum rotation), the rotation should decrease from its maximum to zero at the left edge of the div.

I also included your `div.a` inside another `div.c` because the `mousemove` event wasn't working properly after you apply the css rotation.

Here is the edit of your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ujolop/34/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently somebody has been giving a lot of edits to this.

http://jsbin.com/ujolop/30/edit

The simplest fix was to change the axis you are rotating around.  Secondly, you *might* have to use proprietary prefixes for some browsers, but maybe not what Vucko proposed, as IIRC, `.css` uses the DOM oriented camel case style properties, not the dash properties.

Edit:  If you really want to rotate it around the vertical axis (coplanar with the screen), I suppose you might need your thing that's being rotated be different from the thing that's receiving the events.

There's more than one way to do it, but, take a look at

http://jsbin.com/ujolop/39/edit

Comment: I want to rotate Y and not Z. Why the rotated element should be different than the element receiving the events?

Comment: I don't trust the measurements `width` and `position` provide on a rotated item.  I don't even know what the standard behavior should be in that regard.